# Chasse plugin: can a user be on multiple journeys at the same time?

Tags: email

We are using the wonderful [Chasse plugin](https://github.com/artfulrobot/chasse) to make it more intuitive for our administration team to run e-mail drip campaigns.  As our community has grown and gotten more complex, we now have a need to put a user into multiple drip campaigns at the same time.  I have tried to make this happen but have not been successful.  Does anyone know if this is supported?

Here are the things I have tried:

- Putting the user in the mailing groups for two Chasse journeys.
- Searching for a user who is already on a Chasse journey, then selecting them from a user list and using the drop down option to set a Chasse journey/step for them.  This seems to over-write the Chasse journey they were on previously.

If this is not possible with Chasse, does anyone have examples of configuring drip campaigns with CiviRules?  I find CiviRules a bit complex and easy to screw up so it would be helpful to see some examples.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to submit a request to @artfulrobot, the maintainer of Chassé plugin, to support multiple simultaneous journeys. We at JMA Consulting would provide some funding for this.

Comment: @JoeMurray We would provide some funding for this as well.  I will submit a request to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to artfulrobot in the [MM thread](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/kc6okpkj7bnh7xn6nkeswe35pc), Chassé enforces the concept that one contact can only be on one journey at once

Comment: Maybe one of your more confusing answers Pete!  Presumably this is 'yes' meaning 'yes, I know if this is supported - single journey only'   But for the subject question "can a user be on multiple journeys at the same time" - the answer is No - as you describe.

Comment: indeed. hopefully my most confusing answer by a long shot. fixed.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Yes it is true that a contact cannot be on multiple journeys at once.

Comment: Thank you, Pete.  The answer made sense to me!  :)